# Return readable date format in leaflet popup from ArcGIS map/feature service

Tags: leaflet, esri-leaflet

I'm trying to show dates in popups in a leaflet map that consumes Map Service from ArcGIS Server. the date format is however in UNIX-standard (json: "Bedomdatum": 1228694400000,) and I'm lost when trying to convert these to readable format, such as 2017-12-31.

Any ideas or code snippets that I could learn from?

[Link to Map service](http://ext-geodata.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/WMS/LST_wms_miljodata/MapServer/3/query?where=OBJECTID%20%3D%20160&text=&objectIds=&time=&geometry=&geometryType=esriGeometryPoint&inSR=&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&relationParam=&outFields=*&returnGeometry=true&returnTrueCurves=false&maxAllowableOffset=&geometryPrecision=&outSR=&returnIdsOnly=false&returnCountOnly=false&orderByFields=&groupByFieldsForStatistics=&outStatistics=&returnZ=false&returnM=false&gdbVersion=&returnDistinctValues=false&resultOffset=&resultRecordCount=&queryByDistance=&returnExtentsOnly=false&datumTransformation=&parameterValues=&rangeValues=&f=pjson)

I'm using L.esri.featureLayer to render the objects in the map
https://atgarderivatten.se/karta_funktion

Excerpts of code:

```
    var fiskvagar = L.esri.featureLayer({
    url: 'https://ext-geodata.lansstyrelsen.se/arcgis/rest/services/WFS/LST_WFS_Miljodata/MapServer/2',
    pointToLayer: function (feature, latlng) {
            if(feature.properties.Bedomskick === "Gott") {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: Gott});
            }
            else {
                return L.marker(latlng, {icon: Bedomning_saknas});
            }
    },
}).addTo(map);

fiskvagar.bindPopup(function (evt) {
return L.Util.template('<h2>{FiskvNamn}</h2><table><small>\
<tr><td valign="top"><b>Datum:</b></td><td>{Bedomdatum}</td></tr>\
<tr><td valign="top"><b>ID / länk:</b></td><td><a href="{URL}" target="_blank">{FiskvagID}</a></td></tr>\
</small></table>', evt.feature.properties);
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm lost when trying to convert these to readable format, such as 2017-12-31

Read the documentation for [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). After that, it's quite an easy task:

```
var timestampMsec = 1228694400000;
var myDate = new Date(timestampMsec);
var str = myDate.toDateString();
```

How to put that in your code? There are several ways. One of them would be something like

```
fiskvagar.bindPopup(function(evt){
    var featureDate = new Date(evt.feature.properties.Bedomdatum);
    return "Date: " + featureDate.toDateString();
});
```

If you need finer control over the format, I suggest having a look at https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot.
I added featureDate.toLocaleDateString to get the local format